# How do I call an SSJS method with parameters from javascript

Tags: methods, hash, parameters, xpages, serverside-javascript

I have a url containing a hash e.g http://www.acme.com/home.xsp#key=1234

When the url above loads in the browser I need to call a serverside javascript based on the value in the hash.

I have found a few ways of retriving the hash client side like this

```
var key = getHashUrlVars()["key"];
```

so I have the key available in my client side script in the onclientload event.

So in the same onClientLoad event I now need to call my server side javascript method so I have tried the following

```
'#{javascript:doStuff(key)}' 
'#{javascript:doStuff(' + key + ')}'
```

..and a few other ways. but I can't get it to work.

maybe there is an XSP command I can use instead? 
any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a XSP.partialRefreshPost in CSJS and use parameters to send your data to the server:

```
var p = { "key": getHashUrlVars()["key"] }
XSP.partialRefreshPost( '#{id:_element_to_refresh_}', {params: p} );
```

To access the parameters in SSJS just try this:

```
doStuff( param.key )
```

You could use an empty div-element as a target execute the SSJS code. Or you can use the executeOnServer - method: http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC

Hope this helps

Sven