# How to include client side JavaScript in ssjs in xpages

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to include some results from client side JavaScript (csjs) into my server side JavaScript (ssjs) in XPages.

e.g. on csjs i collect the screenwidth of a device via window.screen.availWidth

I would like to use the result further in my ssjs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the screen width and height from you client script to you server script.

using QueryString (location.href=...../?open&width=xxxx&height=yyyyy),
setting a field on your xpage and to a partialrefresh or using extlib remote service.

There are probably several more ways of doing it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be, you could put your result of CSJS calculation in a hidden input field and then get those values in your SSJS code.

Also you can look into [this discussion in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769674/how-do-i-call-an-ssjs-method-with-parameters-from-javascript) for some more ideas. It basically uses partial refresh and passes the values from CSJS as parameters.

`XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:_element_to_refresh_}', {params: p});`

You could then access those parameters in your SSJS code.

And I would be repeating Fredrik, "there are probably several more ways of doing it" ;-)