# Prevent Server side event from firing until clientside is done

Tags: xpages

I have a button that contains clientside code and serverside code.  The clientside code contains an addCallback function to execute additional code dependent on the result of the first.  This all works fine, but now I am trying to add serverside JS to run AFTER the clientside is completely finished.

For some reason the serverside code and refresh is running after the first RPC is called and skipping the remainder of the clientside code.

Note: My RPC returns a string "true" or "false".

```
message = "Starting Initiate Settlement Process...";
$(".infoMessage").text(message);
atmID = $("input.atmID").val(); //pull from hidden input
settlementCorrectYN = $( "input:checked" ).val();
todayAmt = $( ".todayAmt" ).val();
amtReceived = $( ".amtRec" ).val();

var tranType = "Settlement";
var deferred = atmRPC.closeATMSettle(tranType);
deferred.addCallback(function(result){
    alert("first result=" + result);
```

**SERVER REFRESH RUNS HERE**

```
if (result == "false") {
            message = "Initiate Settlement process failed";
            $(".infoMessage").text(message);
            atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
        } else if (result == "true"){
            var tranType = "Settlement";
            var deferredInner = atmRPC.settleATMInitiate(settlementCorrectYN, tranType, todayAmt, amtReceived, atmID);
            deferredInner.addCallback(function(result){
            alert("inner result=" + result)
            if (result == "false") {
                message = "";
                $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
            } else if(result == "true"){
                message = atmID + " has been successfully Settled."
                $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
            }
            })
        } 
      }
    )
```

This happens if the server refresh is a partial or full refresh.  How can I force the SSJS and accompanying refresh to run ONLY at the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769674/how-do-i-call-an-ssjs-method-with-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: Hi Steve. Is there a reason why you're not running the additional SSJS within the addCallback as a secondary Remote Service call? You could then use the callBack of the second Remote Service and perform a partialRefreshGet/Post in place of the Standard Partial Refresh? This will give you the same effect as running the SSJS the standard way.

Comment: Thanks John! I did get it working using Marky's answer below.  This seems like a good way to go about it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go old school - make your XPages button do no submission and execute your clientside code.

Have a hidden button with a classSelector which also has a style of display:none

in your callback

```
$('.classSelector).click()
```

Where the class selector is added to the XPages button that you want to click

```
<xp:button id="stevesId" styleClass="classSelector"></xp:button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The deferred call is executed in asynchronous way, so the code keeps running and the server code is triggered. You need to change this call to a "synchronous" way. (Although this is strongly not recommended)