# XPages: Handle the parameters in SSJS send by XSP.partialRefreshPost from Client

Tags: ajax, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus, xsp

Can I use an SSJS function if I call an XSP.partialRefreshPost in Client? Where should I define this SSJS function - directly in XSP.partialRefreshPost or in the refreshed object?
Maybe all the steps above are wrong and I should use pure AJAX? The main idea is to send data from client to server via button without using any SSJS in this button, only CSJS

Answer (score 2):

Does the question [**How do I call an SSJS method with parameters from JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769674/how-do-i-call-an-ssjs-method-with-parameters-from-javascript) cover your answer?

Brad Ballasaitis has also blogged about [accessing the parameters from a partialRefreshGet](http://xcellerant.net/2014/07/14/passing-parameters-to-ssjs-from-a-client-side-partialrefreshget/), but the concept and implementation should be the same from partialRefreshPost.

Comment: Not exactly. All this articles describes how to send parameters to server. But I need the article (or example) how to handle this parameters on the server after they've been sent to it. (for example - where should I use function - doStuff( param.key ) if I refresh only a single object on the page and not the entire page). Method "executeOnServer" is quite suitable, but it is a kind of a hack. I thought that there are more "legal" methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions - if you want to do it manually, refer to this post on [xpages.info](http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC)

Or

Look into the XPages JSON RPC Service component

Comment: Thank's for links :) I am also looking in the direction of REST Services